# (Scrapy) Request doesn't work when turning to next page

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to crawl continuous pages so I use scrapy to yield new Request if the current page have next page, but I find it doesn't call Request function. Here is my code and result:

> next page url: http://www.wowsai.com/index.php?app=store&act=credit&id=682376&page=2#module
>
> 2015-05-06 10:00:47+0800 [spider22] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    #2.get the next page url and trigger another request and par
    if "page" not in response.url:
        nextpage_url = 'ht tp://www.wowsai.com/'+sel.xpath('//div[@id="pageBox"]/a[1]/@href').extract()[0]
    else:
        nextpage_url = 'htt p://www.wowsai.com/'+sel.xpath('//div[@id="pageBox"]/a[2]/@href').extract()[0]
    print "next page url:", nextpage_url
    yield Request(nextpage_url, callback=self.parsePage)


def parsePage(self, response):
    print response.url
    print "here is parsePage"
```

Comment: apart from connecting well your strings (`htt p` to `http`), and setting your spider correctly (not just the methods), it looks like it is working. Maybe you should your entire spider code.